# How to load Coucbase extension using NinjectModule

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to load couchbase extension into a ninject repo module and I am not quite sure on how it can be done. In a startup program file I used something like below and it works since I am adding one by one to a serviceprovider  in a .net core project

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
 .AddLogging()     
.AddSingleton<ICacheAdapter, CacheAdapter>()
 .AddCouchbase(c =>
 {
     c.Servers = new List<Uri>
     {
         new Uri("http://couchbase.com/")
     };
 })
 .AddDistributedCouchbaseCache("default", c => { })
 .BuildServiceProvider();
```

But in the repository module, I cannot quite  understand or figure out how to bind the kernel with some implementation so I have the connection info embedded into the cacheadapter

```
Bind<ICacheAdapter>().To<CacheAdapter>().InSingletonScope();
```